# googleApiClient.Builder(this) does not exist

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    buildgoogleclient();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
protected synchronized void buildgoogleclient() {
    mgoogleApiClient=new mgoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
}

}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for, please provide more information and show a bit more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This obviously will not compile

```
mgoogleApiClient= new  mgoogleApiClient
```

You cannot create a `new x` out of a previously undefined `x`. And you can only create `new` from a class, not a field or variable reference

[See Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-api-client), but you meant to do this

```
mgoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
```

Comment: Google has lots of open source example on Github https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples